# Border radius still square internally

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a page that lists some predefined avatars that users can selected, as seen here -

[image]

These are defined as follows -

```
<span class="avatar-box">
    <img src="..." class="avatar" style="width: 100px; height: 100px;" />
</span>  

.avatar-box {
    width: 120px;
    height: 120px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.avatar {
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin: 10px;
}
```

When I click on an avatar, jQuery adds a class of "selected" to "avatar" -

```
.selected {
    border: 10px solid #40ac2b !important;
}
```

However, when this happens, the following happens on Chrome -

[image]

As you can see, while the avatar remains round, the border added is still square. This behaviour does not happen in Firefox, only Chrome.

What can I do to ensure the border remains round, like the avatar itself?

Comment: Can't you add `border-radius: 50%;` to `.selected` as well?

Comment: it adds `selected` on `avatar` or on `avatar-box`?

Comment: @Barmar doing this seems to make no change to the outcome

Comment: @DeepakSharma it adds selected to avatar, not avatar-box

Comment: "the border added is still square." I want to clarify this. Isn't your original image square in the first place?

Comment: weird it works for me, [pen](https://codepen.io/reiallenramos/pen/bxBeLQ)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set default border with transparent color, and after hover/active border color changed, because border size effect the size i.e height and width.

Have a look below example.

```css
body{
  background:#ccc;
}

.avatar-box {
    width: 120px;
    height: 120px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin: 10px;   
}

.avatar {
    border-radius: 50%;   
    border:10px solid transparent; 
}

.avatar:hover{
  border:10px solid #ff0000;  
}
```

```html
<span class="avatar-box">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/CpldL.png?s=328&g=1" class="avatar" style="width: 100px; height: 100px;" />
</span>
```

Comment: Please explain what you changed and, more important, *why*.

Comment: i set default border with transparent color, and after hover/active border color changed, because border size effect the size i.e height and width.

Comment: The explanation should be in the answer, not a comment.